# REST API Resource Granularity

Tags: api, rest, api-design, restful-url

I wanted to get opinion on resource granularity. Say, I have a an domain entity called "magazines". But there are different types of magazines, including Sports, Nature, Automobiles, Computers and Aeroplanes, etc.
When I want to create a new "sports" magazine, should I be using construct such as:

- PUT /magazines
- PUT /sports-magazines
- PUT /magazines/sports

When I want to get a specific *sports* magazine, should I be saying:

- GET /magazines/{id}
- GET /sports-magazines/{id}
- GET /magazines/sports/{id}

If I want to get *sports magazines* for the year 2001, should I be using:

- GET /magazines?type=sports&year=2001
- GET /sports-magazines?year=2001
- GET /magazines/sports?year=2001

And finally, if I want to return how many pages each **type of** magazine has for January 2001 publication, how would I do that? Do I need to create a new *pages* resource for that? Or make two independent requests or something else? First of these is listed below:

- GET /magazines/pages?type1=sports&type2=nature&year=2001&month=01
- GET /sports-magazines/pages?type=nature&year=2001&month=01

Given these scenarios how would you model your resources?

Answer (score 0):

> I have a an domain entity called "magazines". But there are different types of magazines, including Sports, Nature, Automobiles, Computers and Aeroplanes, etc.

Important thing to understand: resources aren't domain entities.  Your resource model is a facade that sits in front of your domain model.

Notice, for example, that this resource ([REST API Resource Granularity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70582668/rest-api-resource-granularity)) describes not only your question, but also my answer.

---

`PUT` probably is NOT what you want for "create a new resource" unless the client is already in position to know what URI should be used for the new resource.  The target URI of a PUT request is the same URI that we expect to use later to GET the data

```
PUT /magazines/{id}
GET /magazines/{id}
```

In the case where we don't expect the client to know what the URI is going to be... well, we don't have an HTTP method that means precisely that, so we fall back to using POST (see [Fielding, 2009](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post)).

```
POST /magazines
```

```
201 Created
Location: /magazines/12345
```

Note that the machines don't care if the URI of the created resource(s) match the target URI of the POST request.

---

REST really doesn't care what spelling conventions you use for your resource identifiers (in much the same way that the machines don't care what spelling conventions you use for variable names).

```
GET /magazines?type=sports&year=2001
GET /sports-magazines?year=2001
GET /magazines/sports?year=2001
GET /magazines/sports/year=2001
GET /magazines/sports/2001
```

Those are all *fine*; there are trade-offs.  Key value pairs encoded into a query string make creating URI with HTML forms easier, using path segments makes relative resolution easier.

---

> I want to return how many pages each type of magazine has for January 2001 publication

Creating a new URI with that information is *fine*.  Extending the schema of your existing resources to include that information is also fine.

Comment: Great answer. The statement "*Your resource model is a facade that sits in front of your domain model.*" sums it up very nicely.

To extend that further, this is how information models could be layered.

* Persistence Model (Physical tables and views)
* Domain Model (As per your functional and domain boundaries)
* Resource Model (how you want to expose your domain model so it's usage is intuitive)

Feel free to define them independently of each other if that helps.